# Get progress when piping through gm

Tags: node.js, gm

On my node app I'm trying to figure out how to see the progress of the stream.
How can I get tell the browser what the progress is?

This is the code I'm using on the server:

```
gm(readStream, 'img.jpg')
   .resize(width, height)
   .quality(quality)
   .stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        stdout.pipe(res);
    });
```

Comment: Have an upvote, i'd like to know the same thing.